# Why is docker not completely deleting my file?

Tags: docker, centos

I am trying to build using:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS builder

COPY pythonnet/src/ pythonnet/src
WORKDIR /pythonnet/src/runtime
RUN dotnet build -f netstandard2.0 -p:DefineConstants=\"MONO_LINUX\;XPLAT\;PYTHON3\;PYTHON37\;UCS4\;NETSTANDARD\" Python.Runtime.15.csproj

# copy myApp csproj and restore
COPY src/myApp/*.csproj /src/myApp/
WORKDIR /src/myApp
RUN dotnet restore

# now copy everything else as separate docker step
# (copy to staging folder, remove csproj, and copy down - so we don't overwrite project above)
WORKDIR /
COPY src/myApp/ ./staging/src/myApp
RUN rm ./staging/src/myApp/*.csproj \
    && cp -r ./staging/* ./ \
    && rm -rf ./staging
```

This was working fine, and in Windows 10 still does, but in CentOS 7 I get:

```
Step 10/40 : RUN rm ./staging/src/myApp/*.csproj  && cp -r ./staging/* ./ && rm -rf ./staging
 ---> Running in 6b17ae0fae89
cp: cannot stat './staging/src/myApp/myApp.csproj': No such file or directory
```

Using `ls` instead of `cp` throws a similar file not found error, so it looks like Docker still knows about `myApp.csproj` but cannot see it since it has been removed.

Is there a way around this? I have tried using `rsync` but similar problems.

Comment: I have tried downgrading docker `sudo yum downgrade docker-ce-`.

Comment: I am confused by your Dockerfile. You restore the csproj to `/src/myApp` on the container but then you overwrite everything in there (except for the csproj file) using stuff from the staging directory. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: a very long shot, is [SELinux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/) enabled?

Comment: @timur it was, yes. I set it to permissive, same error. Unless you meant within the docker container?

Comment: I was going to suggest you to completely disable it - i think `permissive` means SELinux still runs and analyses your policies as per normal. With only difference being it does not enforce anything, just logs evaluation results (which can still lead to it inspecting your files in the background). To your point whether you should disable it in containers - I don't think so as it used to work before.

Comment: Thanks, disabling it didn't help either.

Comment: @Peaceful James. Sorry I missed your comment. Yes it does seem strange, doesn't it? I just inherited the code. Will see if I can find a rationale for doing it this way, but I am open to simplifications. I am a docker newbie.

Comment: Frankly, I think it is incorrect. The intention seems to be "restore the csproj and anything else we're missing copy from host" but that is not what is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply ignored the issue by tacking on `;exit 0` on the offending lines. Not great, but does the job.

EDIT: This worked for me as I cannot upgrade the version of CemtOS. If you can, check out Alexander Block's answer.

Comment: This solution does NOT solve the underlying issue and will actually cause future issues when applied to more critical places. It's just luck in this case that you don't have follow up issues, as the `.csproj` files are simply not needed anymore afterwards.

The correct solution is to upgrade the kernel, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62596848/why-is-docker-not-completely-deleting-my-file/63030971#63030971.

Please remove the "accepted answer" tag from this answer, as otherwise other users might experience more serious issues.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a secure environment that I cannot change.

Comment: This IMHO still does not justify that this answer is marked as correct/accepted, as it is not correct. It's even dangerous, especially when people will later find this question and blindly adapt your solution as it is marked as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically how to solve this problem as there's a lot of context in the filesystem that you haven't (and probably can't) share with us.

My suggestion on a strategy is that you:

1. comment out all lines from the failing one 'til the end of the Dockerfile
2. build the partial image
3. `docker exec -it [image] bash` to jump into the image
4. poke around and figure out what's going wrong
5. repeat 1-4 until things work as expected

It's not as fun as a perfectly insightful answer of course but this is a relentlessly effective algorithm even if it's tedious and annoying.

#### EDIT

My wild guess is that somehow, someway the linux machine doesn't have the file where it's expected for some reason and so it doesn't get copied into the image at all and that's why the docker build process can't find it.  But there's no way to know without debugging the build process.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but that is kind of what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

`cp -r` will stop and fail with that `cannot stat <file>` message whenever the source is a symbolic link and the target of the link does not exist. It will not copy links to non-existent files.

So my guess is that after you run `COPY src/myApp/ ./staging/src/myApp` your file `./staging/src/myApp/myApp.csproj` is a symbolic link to a non-existent file.  Why the following `RUN rm ./staging/src/*.csproj` doesn't remove it and stays silent about that, I don't know the answer to that.

To help demonstrate my theory, see below showing cp failing on a symlink on Centos 7.

```
[547] $ docker run --rm -it centos:7
Unable to find image 'centos:7' locally
7: Pulling from library/centos
524b0c1e57f8: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:e9ce0b76f29f942502facd849f3e468232492b259b9d9f076f71b392293f1582
Status: Downloaded newer image for centos:7
[root@a47b77cf2800 /]# ln -s /tmp/foo /tmp/bar 
[root@a47b77cf2800 /]# ls -l /tmp/foo
ls: cannot access /tmp/foo: No such file or directory
[root@a47b77cf2800 /]# ls -l /tmp/bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Jul  6 05:44 /tmp/bar -> /tmp/foo
[root@a47b77cf2800 /]# cp /tmp/foo /tmp/1 
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/foo': No such file or directory
[root@a47b77cf2800 /]# cp /tmp/bar /tmp/2
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/bar': No such file or directory
```

Notice how you copy reports that it cannot stat either the source or destination of the symbolic link.  It's the exact symptom you are seeing.

If you just want to get past this, you can try `tar` instead of `cp` or `rsync`.

Instead of

```
cp -r ./staging/* ./
```

use this instead:

```
tar -C ./staging -cf - . | tar -xf -
```

tar will happily copy symlinks that don't exist.

Comment: Thanks. Gave `tar: ./src/myApp/myApp.csproj: File removed before we read it`

Comment: So, not a symlink issue then.  It seems like the previous `rm` is too slow. I'm just guessing now, but it sounds like a caching issue, or might even be shell expansion related. The `rm` is deleting the file that `cp` (and `tar` ) has already picked up to read . by the time they start, it's gone.  As an experiment, try breaking up the `&&` chain now, and splitting the `RUN` command into 3 separate `RUN` commands. docker will commit each RUN into it's own layer (not the most efficient) but it might highlight something and provide some clues for you

Comment: Thanks. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've very likely encountered a kernel bug that has been fixed a long time ago in more recent kernels. As of https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS, CentOS 7 is based on the Linux Kernel 3.10, which is pretty old already and does not have good Docker support in regard to the storage backend (overlay filesystem).

CentOS tried to backport needed fixes and features into 3.10, but seems to not have succeeded fully when it comes to overlay support. There are multiple (slightly different) issues regarding this which you can find when searching for "CentOS 7 overlay driver" on the internet. All of them have in common that removing of files from parent overlays does not work as expected.

For me it looks like `rm` calls on files return success, even though the files are not fully removed. Directory listings (e.g. by `ls` or shell expansion as in your case) then still list the file, while accessing the file then fails (no matter if read, write or deletion of the file).

I assume that what you've seen is just another incarnation of these issues. You should either switch to CentOS 8 or upgrade your Kernel (which is not officially supported by CentOS as far as I understand). Or even more radical, switch to a distribution which is used more often in combination with Docker and generally offers more recent Kernels, e.g. Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: @schoon You can verify if you're affected by the underlying bug by simply running the reproducer in https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=11878&nbn=1. Even if the bug report looks unrelated to the issues you observe, it's still the same underlying bug.